# Can't fit glmer in R with 18,000 observations when two proportions are very close

Tags: convergence, large-data

I have a dataset that has 3 levels (institution/provider/1:1 matched pairs) with 18,000 observations.

The matched pairs (subclass) were exactly matched within their institution and might receive different providers within the institution.

My goal is simple: comparing 7 outcomes (all yes/no) between 2 intervention arms. Ideally, I would love to model them jointly. But even now, I have a lot of difficulty fitting just an individual outcome.

Note that some of the 7 outcomes have similar proportions, e.g., 10% vs. 11%.

I would like some advice on how to model this type of data. My errors/issues are:

1. running hours without any result (I had to stop)
2. Is singular
3. Warning seen here

> ```
> Warning in Matrix::rankMatrix(TMBStruc$data.tmb[[whichX]]) :
>   rankMatrix(<large sparse Matrix>, method = 'tolNorm2') coerces to dense matrix.
> Probably should rather use method = 'qr' !?
> Error in solve.default(h, g) : 
>   system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 2.01098e-39
> ```

I tried 5 models below, and only fit5 works:

```r
fit1=glmer(y ~ grp + (1|Institution/Provider) + (1|subclass), 
            data = m, family = binomial())    #singular

fit2=glmer(y ~ grp + (1|Institution/Provider), data = m, 
           family = binomial())

fit3=glmer(y ~ grp + Institution + (1|Institution:Provider) + 
           (1|Institution:subclass), data = m,
           family = binomial())

fit4=glmer(y ~ grp + Institution + (1|Institution:Provider) + 
           (1|subclass), data = m, family = binomial())

fit5=glmmTMB(y ~ +Institution + (1|Provider) + (1|subclass), data = m, 
             family = binomial(), sparseX = c(cond=TRUE), 
             control = glmmTMBControl(
                     profile = TRUE))
summary(fit5)
#only fit5 works
```

Comment: Note that the name of the famous software is R not r! I did an edit